# Playwright Copy from clipboard on ubuntu doesnt work, but on mac it does

Tags: ubuntu, pytest, playwright, playwright-python

#### System info

- Playwright Version: [v1.39]
- Operating System: [Ubuntu 20, macOS 143. etc.]
- Browser: [Chromium]
- Other info: Python 3.12 +pytest

#### Source code

```
   def copy_from_clipboard(self) -> str:
        if os_type == 'posix':
            keyboard = 'Meta'
        else:
            keyboard = 'Control'
        self.element.click()
        self.element.focus()
        self.element.page.keyboard.press(f"{keyboard}+A")
        self.element.page.keyboard.press(f"{keyboard}+C")
        data = self.element.page.evaluate_handle('navigator.clipboard.readText()')
        return data.json_value()
```

The pytest run on CI (ubuntu):

```
text_value = self.saml_page.saml_logout_url_textbox().copy_from_clipboard()
>       assert fields[
                   'samlLoginUrl'] == text_value, f"Expected to be {fields['samlLoginUrl']} but received {text_value}"
E       AssertionError: Expected to be http://localhost.com/ but received 
E       assert 'http://localhost.com/' == ''
E         + http://localhost.com/
tests/authentication/saml_ui_test.py:42: AssertionError
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED tests/authentication/saml_ui_test.py::TestSamlUi::test_enter_saml_fields_verified_they_saved[chromium] - AssertionError: Expected to be http://localhost.com/ but received 
=================== 1 failed, 4 passed in 175.74s (0:02:55) ====================
```

**Steps**
I have this code snippet, which basically copies to clipboard and then return a value.

In a local machine, Macos 14.3 (Apple M1) , it works as expected, and the assertion passes

I tried to do "if/else" and to change the key's to "Control". still doesn't work.

- of course I've enabled the context with permissions (and as said above, works on Mac)

**Expected** :(works as expected in Mac)
assert 'http://localhost.com/' == 'http://localhost.com/'

**Actual** (In linux)

assert 'http://localhost.com/' == ''